# How to create new transaction within existing transaction in Grails

Tags: grails, transactions

I have Machine and Parts domain class

In my service class I am trying to start a transaction, inside that transaction i want to create a new transaction and commit it when it comes out of the inner transaction.

```
Machine.withTransaction { // transaction 1
    // some code to add Parts

    // some code to remove Parts
    Machine.withNewTrasaction { // transaction 2
       // some code to remove Parts.
    } // end of transaction 2

// some code to update couple of columns in machine table.
}// end of transaction 1
```

When it comes out of `transaction 2` I want `transaction 2` be commited the Parts for the Machine irrespective to `transaction 1`.But grails is throwing an error back as `"Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"`
How to commit the `transaction 2` alone separately without considering the `transaction 1`?

Comment: Can you try using `Machine.withNewTransaction(propagation: TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW){...}`?

Comment: @dmahapatro I am getting back error as `No signature of method : Machine.withNewTransaction` i feel the syntax or something is wrong. I am not able to find good documentation also for this

Answer (score 1):

You can try handling transaction explicitly using `@Transactional` annotation inside the service class.

**Notes:-**

- Once you add `@Transactional` annotation to service method, the service class is not deemed transactional by default.
- Since you splitting the functionality into two methods, you have to use the `proxied` instance of the service class to call the second method otherwise you cannot create a new transaction for the second method. Hence, use of `applicationContext` below in method 1.
- You would not need `withTransaction` or `withNewTransaction` block any more.

Service class would look like:

```
class MachineService{
   @Transactional
   def someMethodToAddParts(){
       ......
       grailsApplication.mainContext.machineService.someMethodToRemoveParts()
       ......
   }

   @Transactional(propagation = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)
   def someMethodToRemoveParts(){
     .......
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code in this way                                     `public boolean someMethodToAddParts() {
 withTransaction{
 ...
 grailsApplication.mainContext.machineService.someMethodToRemoveParts()
 ...
 }
}

@Transactional(propagation = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)
protected boolean someMethodToRemoveParts(){
 ...
 parts.save()
  
}`

Comment: In my first method if the transaction roll back is set or any other error for that matters, it should have persisted the Parts table via someMethodToRemoveParts. But when the response comes out of the someMethodToAddParts() with the error it hasnt persisted the parts in DB. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @user2001627 Isn't `someMethodToRemoveParts()` meant to remove Parts instead of persisting it? And you need not provide `withTransaction` if you are using the annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it has to remove the Parts it is removing the parts from machine(might in the proxy object) but it is not committing if `someMethodToAddParts()` set roll back. I was expecting no matter what, `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` has been set so it would commit it in DB after the flow comes out `someMethodToAddParts()`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a slightly different problem, maybe it can help somebody, and maybe it could help for the above problem.

I think that the above problem could be avoided by merging entities to the new transaction, then use .merge() method on the collection causing the problem.

First I think the above code looks like this (I've added comments to explain) :

```
Machine.withTransaction { // transaction 1
    // some code to add Parts

    yourEntity.addToParts(...)

    // some code to remove Parts
    Machine.withNewTrasaction { // transaction 2
       // some code to remove Parts.

       yourEntity.removeFromParts(...)


    } // end of transaction 2 -> the session is flushed, and the transaction is committed
      // during the flush, hibernate detect that "parts" collection is already attached
      // to another session, in another transaction then throw "Illegal 
      // attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"

// some code to update couple of columns in machine table.
}
```

Then the solution is to merge the collection to the new transaction, it give us something like this :

```
Machine.withTransaction { // transaction 1
    // some code to add Parts

    yourEntity.addToParts(...)

    // some code to remove Parts
    Machine.withNewTrasaction { // transaction 2
       // some code to remove Parts.

       yourEntity.removeFromParts(...)
       // Merging the collection to the session
       yourEntity.merge() // I haven't tried but maybe you need ensure 
                          // there is a merge cascade on "parts" collection

    } // end of transaction 2 -> the session is flushed, and the transaction is committed

// some code to update couple of columns in machine table.
}
```

In my case, with a merge in the new transaction, I solved the error message "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [yourPackage.YourEntity]" (when I talk about YourEntity, you can also read YourDomaineClass)